# How to get MUI Material-UI Blog template to load in Vite

Tags: material-ui, markdown, vite

I loaded the [material mui example](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/example-projects/) using viteJS into stackblitz.

Then the README.md for the Templates > Blog reads as follows:

1. Copy the files into your project, or one of the example projects.
2. Make sure your project has the required dependencies: @mui/material, @mui/icons-material, @emotion/styled, @emotion/react, markdown-to-jsx.
3. Import and use the Blog component.

I know I messed up the process trying to follow the README.md file but I didn't know how to "Copy the files into one of the examples"  How am I supposed to copy the blog template into a running vite example?  Also how do you do step #3

Then I went back to an original Example ViteJS and tried following the directions again.  Long Story short I could not get that working either.

So back to the mess I started with. I get the page to load but I end up with the .md files not displaying.

### From the firehose

/src/blog-post.1.md/src/blog-post.2.md/src/blog-post.3.md

#### Blog.jsx

```
const posts = [post1, post2, post3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the steps listed in README.md for the template will work if you keep these addition steps in mind.

1. Step 1 copy the raw code from each file into your active 'src' directory (be sure to use the jsx extension instead of the listed .js from the Blog template)

```
src
   Blog.jsx
   Main.jsx
   Home.jsx  // replaced main.jsx and updated it in index.html
   ... .jsx
```

Keep all the original Vite app files (you can remove them later to format them as you see fit).

2. Run npm install for step 2 but remove the ',' from the list
3. Now in main.jsx - not to be confused with Main.jsx replace

```
App to Blog
import App from './App';
<App />
```

assetsInclude is required in vite.config.js, without it I go back to the error and the page does not load

#### vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.md'],
});
```